# Trying to return a vector from a templated function throws compiling errors.

Tags: c++, templates, vector

Problem is as follow: The following test throws huge amounts of compiler errors.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class test{
   vector<T> vec;
public:
   vector<T>::iterator begin();

};

template<class T>
vector<T>::iterator test<T>::begin(){
  return vec.begin();
}

int main(){

  test<float> testing;
  testing.begin();

}
```

Some Compiler errors:

```
 test.cpp(8): warning C4346: 'std::vector<T>::iterator' : dependent name is not a type
 test.cpp(8): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'begin'
 test.cpp(13): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'test<T>::begin'
```

However, if you swap out the templated `vector<T>` for say, `vector<float>`  its compiles just fine. For example:

```
template<class T>
class test{
   vector<T> vec;
public:
   vector<float>::iterator begin();

};

template<class T>
vector<float>::iterator test<T>::begin(){
   return vec.begin();
}
```

Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `typename` in two places:

```
typename vector<T>::iterator begin();
```

and

```
typename vector<T>::iterator test<T>::begin()
```

By adding `typename`, you are telling the compiler **how** to parse the code. Basically, by adding `typename`, you are telling the compiler to parse the declaration as a type.

Please read [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for an in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `typename` keyword to distinguish that `vector<T>::iterator` is referring to a scoped type, and not a scoped data or function member:

```
template<class T>
class test{
   vector<T> vec;
public:
   typename vector<T>::iterator begin();

};

template<class T>
typename vector<T>::iterator test<T>::begin(){
  return vec.begin();
}
```

Comment: It *is* a member -- just a member *type*, not a member variable.

Answer (score -2):

In C++ template classes, template member functions must have their body defined inside the class, because the template parameter  does not exist outside of the class. The last two error look like what a compiler produces when unfamiliar context causes it to misinterpret perfectly valid syntax. Try moving the function body inside the class.

Comment: This isn't true. The definition of the template must be visible where the template is instantiated, but it doesn't have to be inside the class declaration.

Comment: Sorry. I was thinking of splitting the template across multiple files. My bad.

Comment: No worries, just wanted to clarify so nobody gets too confused. You might want to edit/delete your answer for clarity, though.